# Как обратиться к переменной класса внутри метода?

Tags: php

Есть класс:

```
class Page {
    public $db;

    function writeint() {
      echo $db;
    }

}
```

И код:

```
$page = new Page();
$page->db = 10;
$page->writeint();
```

В итоге получаю

> Notice: Undefined variable: db

Как решить эту проблему? Что сделать, чтобы `$db` была доступна внутри метода?
Заранее отмечу, что в `$db` будет храниться подключение к базе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Page {
   public $db;

   function writeint() {
      echo $this->db;
   }

}
```

Вы забыли использовать псевдо-переменную `$this`, которая всегда указывает на текущий объект.

Comment: `$this` - это **не** модификатор.... Это псевдо переменная.....указатель который всегда относится к текущему объекту.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что ж не исправили? )

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Прошу прощения, ошибся

Answer (score 0):

Здесь можете почитать за псевдо-переменную $this:

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Так же область видимости переменной $db лучше ограничить как private. Почитать можете здесь:

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php